# Testing formsets in Django

Tags: django, forms, unit-testing, formsets

How do I pass the values of a formset in a unit test using client `self.client.post('/url/', {})`? I am getting a validation error saying management_form tampered.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform you need to post the values for the management form as well as your formset

Answer (score 1):

This is an example formset getting user's skills

```
class SkillForm(forms.Form):
    level_id = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, required = True)
    txt_skills = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required = True)

SkillFormset = formset_factory(SkillForm,extra=1, max_num=10)
```

and this the sample POST data for test cases.

```
self.post_data.update({
        'skillform-0-level_id': '2',
        'skillform-0-txt_skills': 'Python',
        'skillform-1-level_id': '3',
        'skillform-1-txt_skills': 'Java',
        'skillform-TOTAL_FORMS': '2',
        'skillform-INITIAL_FORMS': '1',
        'skillform-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '10'
        })
```